# AsyncTaskLoader doesn't run

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I want to implement an AsyncTaskLoader in my project using the Compatibility Package, so I followed the Loader manual in Android Docs.

The problem is that the Loader does nothing, it seems `loadInBackground()` is never called

Any idea of what's wrong in my code? 
(`ExpandableListFragment` extends `Fragment`,but doesn't override any critical method )

Thank you :-)

/**EDIT:

**I realized (late, I'm a moron) that AsyncTaskLoader is an abstract class so I need to subclass it... m(__)m
I leave the question in case someone comes here behind me, who knows...**

```
public class AgendaListFragment extends ExpandableListFragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<JSONArray> {

    private TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Evento>> mItems = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Evento>>();
    private AgendaListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda, container);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new AgendaListAdapter(getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<JSONArray> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return new AsyncTaskLoader<JSONArray>(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public JSONArray loadInBackground() {

                return getDataFromService(AgendaServices.LISTADO_MES);

            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<JSONArray> loader, JSONArray data) {

        // Some stuff to turn JSONArray into TreeMap

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdapter.setItems(mItems);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<JSONArray> arg0) {
        mAdapter.setItems(null);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `AsyncTaskLoader` seems to be missing lots of stuff, like `deliverResults()`. I have two `AsyncTaskLoader` implementations in my `LoaderEx` project you might want to examine for comparison purposes: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

Comment: It seems I'm a mess and I didn't realize it's an abstract class... So now I know why I only found a few examples subclassing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think the best solution for the Compatibility package is to override the **AsyncTaskLoader.onStartLoading** method.

e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
  if(dataIsReady) {
    deliverResult(data);
  } else {
    forceLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this at the end :-D. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah thanks david! Wrote this up into an post with source code: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-asynctask-loader-using-support-library/

Comment: Checking for `takeContentChanged` seems an important step too.

Answer (score 8):

This is exactly a fix but it should work.  I am pretty sure the compatibility library is broken.  Try this:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
```

Comment: This is another way to do it :-D.

Comment: This would work, but it's probably better practice to implement your `Loader<D>` properly (as davidshen84 suggests, by implemenitng the `onStartLoading()` method) instead of calling `forceLoad()` directly in your `Activity` and/or `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3):

[Cheok Yan Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72437/cheok-yan-cheng) is absolutely right:

> Checking for takeContentChanged seems an important step too.

If you write your method like this:

```
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}
```

you ''ll notice that when a child activity comes up and then you return to the parent one, `onStartLoading` (and so `loadInBackground`) are called again!

What can you do?
Set an internal variable (`mContentChanged`) to true inside the constructor; then check this variable inside `onStartLoading`. Only when it's true, start loading for real:

```
package example.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

public abstract class ATLoader<D> extends AsyncTaskLoader<D> {

    public ATLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // run only once
        onContentChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        // That's how we start every AsyncTaskLoader...
        // -  code snippet from  android.content.CursorLoader  (method  onStartLoading)
        if (takeContentChanged()) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at discussion at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14944, checking for `takeContentChanged` seems to be important step too.

```
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        deliverResult(mCursor);
    }
    if (takeContentChanged() || mCursor == null) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in using `takeContentChanged` here - it won't affect result. If `mCursor` is null - `forceLoad` will be called. If it is not - `deliverResult` will be called.

Comment: Why do you say `takeContentChanged` has no point? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html Google's example does make use of that.

Comment: Because when an activity enter `onPause()` and comes back with `onResume()` the loader is notified and will call `onStartLoading()` again. So `takeContentChanged()` (if `onContentChanged()` was called previously) will force to update `mCursor` with last available changes. However, on the first `if` I'd put instead `if (mCursor != null && !takeContentChanged())`.

Answer (score 0):

I took the source code of `CursorLoader` from android framework, and wrote a `CustomTaskLoader<T>` class to ease the job.

https://github.com/Palatis/danbooru-gallery-android/blob/new_api/DanbooruGallery/src/main/java/tw/idv/palatis/danboorugallery/android/content/CustomTaskLoader.java

you basically implement these two functions:

```
public abstract T runTaskInBackground(CancellationSignal signal);
public abstract void cleanUp(T oldResult);
```

see the usage in the activities and fragments, for example this one:
(well my code just ignores the `CancellationSignal`, it's a `TODO` in my list, but you're free to use it.)

https://github.com/Palatis/danbooru-gallery-android/blob/new_api/DanbooruGallery/src/main/java/tw/idv/palatis/danboorugallery/PostListFragment.java

```
return new CustomTaskLoader<Cursor>(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) 
{
    @Override
    public Cursor runTaskInBackground(CancellationSignal signal)
    {
        return SiteSession.getAllPostsCursor(PostListAdapter.POST_COLUMNS);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanUp(Cursor oldCursor)
    {
        if (!oldCursor.isClosed())
            oldCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem after migrating from CursorLoader to AsyncTaskLoader.

[documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html): *Subclasses of `Loader<D>` generally must implement at least **onStartLoading(), onStopLoading(), onForceLoad(), and onReset()**.*

AsyncTaskLoader extends Loader but not implements **onStartLoading(), onStopLoading(), onReset()**. You must implement it by yourself!

@davidshen84 proposed good solution. I only added checking for takeContentChanged.

```
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    try {
        if (data != null) {
            deliverResult(data);
        }
        if (takeContentChanged() || data == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onStartLoading() ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Using forceLoad() is ok (not a bad practice). See what documentation [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#forceLoad()): 
*You generally should only call this when the loader is started - that is, isStarted() returns true.*

Answer (score -2):

I was still having the problem that loading of data was not called. I finally removed the **AsyncTaskLoader** (the support library version) and used only **AsyncTask** (not from support library) to do the job. And it worked.

It could be enough for your needs too.

Description and example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

You have to extend the class **AsyncTask**.

The method **doInBackground** will do the work and in the method **onPostExecute** you will get the result. For starting the **AsyncTask**, you will call the method **execute** on its instance. See the link.

Comment: AsyncTask and AsyncTaskLoader are quite different things...the AsyncTaskLoader has several advantages. You should research a little bit more