# Using Loaders with sqlite query that returns object

Tags: android, android-sqlite, loader

Here's what I've been doing all this while to get data from my database - my fragment will call a dbhelper which will run the query and pass the resulting data in an object.

I should have used a loader so that the querying is not done in the UI thread, but previously I didn't bother since my app's database is very small. Moving forward, this was a bad idea since my app has grown larger and so do the database. So now I'm reading all I can about Loaders including CursorLoader and custom loaders, but I still have problem implementing it in my app.

So here's my current code (simplified, just to show the relevant parts):

```
public class CategoryEdit extends Fragment{

private DbControl dbc;
private ObjectCategory objCategory;
private int categoryID = 3;
private EditText etName;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dbc = new DbControl(getActivity());
        try{
            dbc.open();
            objCategory = new ObjectCategory();
            objCategory = dbc.getCategoryData(categoryID);
            dbc.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        etName.setText(objCategory.name);
    }
}

public class DbControl {

    public static final String FILE_NAME = "DbControl.java";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public DbControl(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public ObjectCategory getCategoryData(int itemID) throws Exception{
        ObjectCategory objCategory = new ObjectCategory();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORY, new String[] {"name"},
                "id = " + itemID, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            objCategory.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        }
        return objCategory;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, in implementing Loader the right way in my case here? If possible, I don't want to alter the codes inside class DbControl too much - especially the return data type of the functions inside it.

Btw amongst the tutorials about loaders that I've read is:

- http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/60331340133/very-simple-example-of-a-loader-and-loadermanager - but this was written more than 3 years ago and it uses Runnable to execute getSupportLoaderManager, and I've not seen other examples/tutorials that does this, so I'm afraid this article is outdated. Furthermore it uses CursorLoader, which from my understanding can only return cursor.
- http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/ - this seems to deal with CursorLoader too

Anyway here's what I've done so far:

```
public class CategoryEdit extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ObjectCategory> {

@Override
    public Loader<ObjectCategory> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
        try{
            dbc.open();
            objCategory = new ObjectCategory();
            objCategory = dbc.getCategoryData(categoryID);
            dbc.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return objCategory; //this returns error, it says required Loader<ObjectCategory> instead of objCategory, but I'm not sure how to do that here
    }

@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ObjectCategory> cursorLoader, ObjectCategory cursor) {
//Since onCreateLoader has error above, I'm not sure how to implement this part
    }

@Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ObjectCategory> cursorLoader) {
        //Can I just leave this empty?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone point me in the right direction, in implementing Loader the right way in my case here?

You have to use an AsyncTaskLoader like this:

```
public class CategoryEdit extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ObjectCategory> {

    @Override
    public Loader<ObjectCategory> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new AsyncTaskLoader<ObjectCategory>(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public ObjectCategory loadInBackground() {
                try {
                    dbc.open();
                    objCategory = new ObjectCategory();
                    objCategory = dbc.getCategoryData(categoryID);
                    dbc.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return objCategory;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                forceLoad();
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ObjectCategory> loader, ObjectCategory data) {
        //do some stuff here
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ObjectCategory> loader) {
        //Yes, you can leave it empty
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your method, but the codes inside loadInBackground is not called. I added forceload as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606048/asynctaskloader-doesnt-run but this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: OK I added `@Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                if (takeContentChanged())
                    forceLoad();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onStopLoading() {
                cancelLoad();
            }` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I would say - don't use `Loaders`. I used `CursorLoader` in my app when I was new to Android, and it turned out to be a bad decision.

If `CursorLoader` is sufficient for your needs, then you're alright (though your `Activities` and `Fragments` will become polluted with DB related logic), but once you try to implement your own `Loader`, that should encapsulate DB related logic and just return a constructed object, you'll inevitably bump into a million issues with `LoaderManager` framework. @CommonsWare wrote a [nice article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/03/31/cwac-loaderex-failed-abstractions.html) about it - read it before you integrate `Loaders` into your app.

Nowadays I usually use "managers" for loading data from SQLite or internet. The general form of my "manager" is like this (please note that these "managers" are not Singletons):

```
public class TutorialManager {

    interface TutorialManagerListener {
        void onDataFetchCompleted(SomeData data);
    }
    private BackgroundThreadPoster mBackgroundThreadPoster;
    private MainThreadPoster mMainThreadPoster;


    private Set<TutorialManagerListener> mListeners = new HashSet<>(1);

    public TutorialManager(@NonNull BackgroundThreadPoster backgroundThreadPoster,
                           @NonNull MainThreadPoster mainThreadPoster) {
        mBackgroundThreadPoster = backgroundThreadPoster;
        mMainThreadPoster = mainThreadPoster;
    }

    @UiThread
    public void registerListener(@NonNull TutorialManagerListener listener) {
        mListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @UiThread
    public void unregisterListener(@NonNull TutorialManagerListener listener) {
        mListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @UiThread
    private void notifyFetchCompleted(SomeData data) {
        for (TutorialManagerListener listener : mListeners) {
            listener.onDataFetchCompleted(data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call to this method will fetch data on background thread and then notify all registered
     * listeners about new data on UI thread.
     */
    public void fetchData() {
        mBackgroundThreadPoster.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // logic that loads the data on background thread goes here
                // final SomeData data = ... ;

                mMainThreadPoster.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        notifyFetchCompleted(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Implementation of `MainThreadPoster`:

```
/**
 * This class should be used in order to execute {@link Runnable} objects on UI thread
 */
public class MainThreadPoster {

    private final Handler mMainHandler;

    public MainThreadPoster() {
        mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Post {@link Runnable} for execution on main thread
     */
    public void post(Runnable runnable) {
        mMainHandler.post(runnable);
    }

}
```

Implementation of `BackgroundThreadPoster` is up to you.I usually use the following simple implementation (unless some fine tuning is required):

```
/**
 * This class should be used in order to execute {@link Runnable} objects on background threads
 */
public class BackgroundThreadPoster {

    private final ExecutorService mBackgroundExecutor;

    public BackgroundThreadPoster() {
        mBackgroundExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    /**
     * Post {@link Runnable} for execution on a random background thread
     */
    public void post(Runnable runnable) {
        mBackgroundExecutor.execute(runnable);
    }

}
```

I inject `MainThreadPoster` and `BackgroundThreadPoster` objects into "managers" in order to:

1. Make "managers" unit-testable
2. Perform centralized management and optimization of background threading across entire application

Comment: wow thanks for another perspective on Loaders and another approach.. I might look at this later. Btw IINM I read some place suggesting that RxJava is another better approach compared to Loaders... you thought on this?

Comment: @imin, I'm not an expert on RxJava, but I think that it is more than just an alternative to loaders - it is entirely different architectural style for application. From what I understand, RxJava will be somewhat similar to the "managers" approach I described in this answer - it is based on Observables and Notifications (aka. listeners).